# How to upgrade elasticsearch in ELK Docker Image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elk

I have installed an elk docker image on a Linux server using the following command:

```
sudo docker pull sebp/elk
```

This pulls the latest version of the elk docker image, which is 7.8.0, and each service in the stack (`elasticsearch`, `logstash`, and `kibana`) also has version 7.8.0.

I need to upgrade `elasticsearch` to 7.9.0 for security reasons. How can I do this while continuing to use the `sebp/elk` docker image?

Comment: This is a good reason to run Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana in separate containers, possibly managed by Docker Compose; then you could just update the image version for the specific unit of software you need.  You'd have to get that image's Dockerfile, update the versions installed in it, and re-run `docker build` to update it.

Comment: Also, Kibana minor version must match Elasticsearch minor version, if you upgrade elasticsearch to 7.9.X you also need to upgrade Kibana to 7.9.X.

Comment: Just changing the image version and restarting with 'docker-compose up` worked for me. Careful, this is not the official upgrade recommandation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elk comes up package and runs all 3 services and links them by default. With this setup, you can’t split and upgrade only elasticsearch.

I recommend you to run all three services independently using docker-compose. So that each service can have an image of your choice.

Sample docker-compose for your reference:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: IMAGE_GOES_HERE
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
      # see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    image: IMAGE_GOES_HERE
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: IMAGE_GOES_HERE
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
> ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/local/home/user/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/net/server/.../merged\\\" at \\\"/net/server/.../usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?

Comment: It seems to create the `.yml` files as directories if they don't already exist.